# Caffe: How to output probabilities and class labels per image to file with lmdb?

Tags: caffe

I have a network I am trying to test using caffe- however I have lots of test images and would like to use lmdb blobs to speed up the testing/experimentation process (as opposed to doing it image by image in MatCaffe/PyCaffe). At the end I would like to have a file that outputs something like:

```
ImageXXXXX prob1 prob2 ... probk argmaxlabel1 argmaxlabel2 ... argmaxlabelk
```

for each of the 1-k top guesses, where each line of this file is the image being tested.

I know how to modify the prototxt files to get the probabilities, argmax, and do logging, but I can't seem to figure out how to write it to a file in this specific way.

Anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT**

Added this to the bottom of my prototxt:

```
layer {
  name: "hdf5out"
  type: "HDF5Output"
  bottom: "data"
  bottom: "prob"
  hdf5_output_param {
    file_name: "temp.h5"
  }
}
```

and I generate the following errors:

```
I0317 13:27:35.451179 31624 hdf5_output_layer.cpp:32] Saving HDF5 file temp.h5
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.11) thread 140368229194176:
  #000: ../../../src/H5D.c line 170 in H5Dcreate2(): unable to create dataset
    major: Dataset
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #001: ../../../src/H5Dint.c line 439 in H5D__create_named(): unable to create and link to dataset
    major: Dataset
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #002: ../../../src/H5L.c line 1638 in H5L_link_object(): unable to create new link to object
    major: Links
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #003: ../../../src/H5L.c line 1882 in H5L_create_real(): can't insert link
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Unable to insert object
  #004: ../../../src/H5Gtraverse.c line 861 in H5G_traverse(): internal path traversal failed
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Object not found
  #005: ../../../src/H5Gtraverse.c line 641 in H5G_traverse_real(): traversal operator failed
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Callback failed
  #006: ../../../src/H5L.c line 1674 in H5L_link_cb(): name already exists
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Object already exists
F0317 13:27:35.451373 31624 hdf5.cpp:101] Check failed: status >= 0 (-1 vs. 0) Failed to make float dataset data
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
```

It seems to be relatively similar to this [post](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/1726), however the link to that solution is a different version of caffe (eg, in my version, there is no file data_layers.hpp - I only have data_layer.hpp )/

Comment: have you considered `"HDF5Output"` layer?

Comment: I haven't, do you have to use hdf5 input in order to use hdf5 output? When I tried using lmdb with hdf5output it gives me an error as if its trying to create an input.

Comment: I haven't used HDF5Output myself. But you don't need hdf input in order to use it

Comment: Hm, yea, I'm stumped. If it can be used, I'm not sure how. I updated the post to show what I've tried and the errors generated.

Comment: For those that find this in the future- caffe strips information about images when it creates blobs, so obtaining per image results is impossible in caffe's current state, unless each blob contains only one image ... kind of defeating the point :-/